# Xcode Swift - This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key uri

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to add data to Core Data, which I think i'm on the right track (I'm fairly new to this so, apologies) From the code below, my 'Aim' is to check the Core Data and if it's empty add the default data.

Code:

```
class func musicIsEmpty(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext)-> Bool{

    let defaultMusic = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Music", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    let defaultMusicSetOne = NSManagedObject(entity: defaultMusic!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as? Music
    //defaultMusicSetOne = NSManagedObject(entity: defaultMusic!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as? Music
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Music")
    fetchRequest.entity = defaultMusic

    defaultMusicSetOne!.uri = "spotify:track:1puJlKuYGH58SAFgXREUpE"
    defaultMusicSetOne!.duration = 30.0
    defaultMusicSetOne!.starttime = 49.0
    defaultMusicSetOne!.xfade = 10.0
    defaultMusicSetOne!.voiceover = "1.25s Next Up.mp3"

    do{
        if let MusicSetResults =  try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject]{

            if MusicSetResults == 0
            {
                defaultMusic!.setValue(defaultMusicSetOne?.uri, forKey: "uri")
                defaultMusic!.setValue(defaultMusicSetOne?.duration, forKey: "duration")
                defaultMusic!.setValue(defaultMusicSetOne?.starttime, forKey: "starttime")
                defaultMusic!.setValue(defaultMusicSetOne?.xfade, forKey: "xfade")
                defaultMusic!.setValue(defaultMusicSetOne?.voiceover, forKey: "voiceover")
                return true
            }

            else
            {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError{
        print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
    return false
}
```

Music.Swift:

```
extension Music {

@NSManaged var voiceover: String?
@NSManaged var xfade: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var duration: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var starttime: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var uri: String?

}
```

But I keep getting the error "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key uri" i'm sure this will be for all .setValues. I'm not sure why this is showing as defaultMusic does have the "uri" field and  defaultMusic is also an instance of Music Object. Is the format of .setValue wrong? or is it something else?

Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What type is `uri`? The error basically says "I expect the key uri to be of type X but you gave me type Y". Also, where do you get the error? in `if MusicSetResults == 0`?

Comment: uri is type String, and yes the error is in-side if MusicSetResults == 0 where i set the .setValues

Comment: Why do you set those values by `setValue`? Can't you just set them normally?

Comment: I'm new to IOS / Xcode / Swift -> and i've just been following tutorials. and most of them show for example "person.setValue("Bart", forkey: "name")" so i'm just trying to use that. is there no need to use setValue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you actually mean this:

**Check if the entity is empty, if yes insert a new object with default values**

```
class func musicIsEmpty(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext)-> Bool {

  let musicEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Music", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!      
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
  fetchRequest.entity = musicEntity
  do {
    let musicSetResults =  try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Music]
    if musicSetResults.isEmpty
    {
      let defaultMusicSetOne = NSManagedObject(entity: musicEntity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Music
      defaultMusicSetOne.uri = "spotify:track:1puJlKuYGH58SAFgXREUpE"
      defaultMusicSetOne.duration = 30.0
      defaultMusicSetOne.starttime = 49.0
      defaultMusicSetOne.xfade = 10.0
      defaultMusicSetOne.voiceover = "1.25s Next Up.mp3"
      return true
    }
  }
  catch let error as NSError{
    print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
  }
  return false
}
```

You might consider also to save the managed object context to make the new object persistent.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! yes thats what I changed it too from your last comment. Yeah i'm trying to implement the save managed object as we speak lol

Answer (score 0):

`defaultMusic` is a `NSEntityDescription`, not a `Music` object.

(Sometimes letting Swift use default data types can be confusing.)

Comment: Ah okay! I see so instead of "defaultMusic" I should really use `defaultMusicSetOne!.setValue(defaultMusicSetOne?.uri, forKey: "uri") `